# Javascript: which Dom event can be bound to Input type=date element?

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to check if users are under the legal age for part time job based on their birthday. This is what I have done so far.

```
<script>
function ageCheck() {
    var date=new Date();
    var year=date.getFullYear();
    var month=date.getMonth()+1;
    var bday=document.getElementById("bday").value;
    var bdayArr=bday.split("-");
    var bYear=bdayArr[0];
    var bMonth=bdayArr[1];
    var bDay=bdayArr[2];
}
</script>

<span class="error">*</span>
<label for="bday">
<span class="register">Birthday</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span id="ageInfo"></span>
<input type="date" name="bday" required="required" onblur="ageCheck()">
```

Comment: `getElementById("bday")` - Your HTML has no such element.

Comment: + Like any other input type, `onchange` or `oninput` are the place you'll want to listen...

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to 'input' event, as this is the standard event for either change or copy-paste event. You should change the input element like this,

```
<input type="date" name="bday" required="required" oninput="ageCheck(this.value)">
```

And Change your function to get the value in parameter.

```
function ageCheck(date) { console.log(date);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I make simple example with your `html`. You can see it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cg131i?embed=1&file=index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `onblur`, you can do it like that.

```js
function ageCheck() {
  var bdayString = birthday.value;
  bdayString = bdayString.split("-")
  
  var bdayNumber = [];
  bdayString.map( val =>{
    bdayNumber.push(parseInt(val))
  })
 
  var year = bdayNumber[0];
  var month = bdayNumber[1];
  var day = bdayNumber[2];
  // if legal age is 18
  legalAge = 18;
  if( 2019 - year >= legalAge){
    console.log( true);
  }
}
```

```html
  <span class="error">*</span>
  <label for="bday"><span class="register">Birthday</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="ageInfo"></span>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="bday" required="required" onblur="ageCheck()" vamue="">
```